# Combine 2 different xml tags based on common attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a xml with the following example

```
<Message>
 <Person>
  <Key>111</Key>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
 </Person>
 <Person>
  <Key>112</Key>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
 </Person>
 <Person>
  <Key>113</Key>
  <Name>Sean</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
 </Person>
 <Car>
  <Key>111</Key>
  <Make>Toyota</Make>
  <Model>Camry</Model>
 </Car>
 <Car>
  <Key>111</Key>
  <Make>Toyota</Make>
  <Model>Corolla</Model>
 </Car>
 <Car>
  <Key>112</Key>
  <Make>Honda</Make>
  <Model>Civic</Model>
 </Car>
 <Car>
  <Key>113</Key>
  <Make>Lexus</Make>
  <Model>G300</Model>
 </Car>
</Message>
```

I would like to create a xml with the following using xslt:

```
<Message>
  <Person>
    <Key>111</Key>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </Person>
  <Car>
    <Key>111</Key>
    <Make>Toyota</Make>
    <Model>Camry</Model>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Key>111</Key>
    <Make>Toyota</Make>
    <Model>Corolla</Model>
  </Car>
</Message>
```

I want to create a Message segment for each key and have the `<person>` and `<car>` segments in there for each key. How can I do this with xslt 2.0?

Comment: Well, you have tagged is as a grouping problem so use `xsl:for-each-group`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples for examples or your favourite XSLT text book (https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is one for instance, available as a free download and has sections dedicated to grouping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `for-each-group` as suggested in a comment use

```
  <xsl:template match="Message">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="Key">
          <Message>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </Message>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

full stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Message">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="Key">
          <Message>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </Message>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Message">
        <xsl:for-each select="Person[Key = following-sibling::Car/Key]">
            <Message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Car[Key = current()/Key]"/>
            </Message>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
Check it
```